# How can I see Log4J output from a Java class started with Ant?

Tags: ant, log4j

When running a Java class through Ant, I was having a lot of trouble getting Log4J output, even though the log4.properties was on the classpath.  Documenting it here in case anyone else has the same problem.

E.g.

```
<java classname="Hello" fork="true">      
    <classpath> 
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>     
    </classpath>
</java>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be solved using something like the following:

```
<property name="log4j" value="file:///${basedir}/log4j.properties"/>
...
<java classname="Hello" fork="true">   
    <sysproperty key="log4j.configuration" value="${log4j}"/>
    <classpath> 
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>     
    </classpath>
</java>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're curious to see where log4j is looking for it's configuration files, try setting the `log4j.debug` system property.

```
<java classname="Hello" fork="true">
  <sysproperty key="log4j.debug" value="true" />
  <classpath>
    …
  </classpath>
</java>
```

That will print information on stderr saying where it's looking for it's configuration files.  There's a brief mention of this in the [manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).